# How to add another entry in the same subheading

Tags: resume

I am using the source code here to format my resume: https://github.com/arasgungore/arasgungore-CV/blob/main/main.tex

So, in my current company I have changed positions over the years. How do I reflect this in this CV code? The code uses the following custom commands:

```
\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-2pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubSubheading}[2]{
    \vspace{-2pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textit{\small#1} & \textit{\small #2} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
```

And here is the sample code for the experience section:

```
%----------- WORK EXPERIENCE -----------

\section{Work Experience}
  \vspace{3pt}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    
    \resumeSubheading
      {SESTEK Speech Enabled Software Technologies}{Istanbul, Turkey}
      {Natural Language Processing R\&D Intern}{Jan 2022 \textbf{--} Feb 2022}
        \resumeItemListStart
            \resumeItem{Implemented common NLP tasks using transformers such as named-entity recognition (NER), part-of-speech (POS) tagging, sentiment analysis, text classification, and extractive/generative question answering.}
            \resumeItem{Built a generative question answering system via Dense Passage Retrieval (DPR) and Retrieval-Augmented Generation (RAG) using the Haystack framework with Python.}
            \resumeItem{Worked on a custom Turkish open-domain question answering system by fine-tuning a BERT base model transformer. Evaluated the exact match and F1 scores using different Turkish data sets and compared the evaluation results.}
        \resumeItemListEnd
    
    % \resumeSubheading
      % {Ankara Metropolitan Municipality}{Ankara, Turkey}
      % {SCADA Engineering Intern}{Aug 2021 \textbf{--} Sep 2021}
        % \resumeItemListStart
            % \resumeItem{Designed GSM/GPRS-based electrical control panels that are connected to local water pump automation systems. Pump station panels use digital output data received from the SCADA control center via RF transmission to control valves and pumps. Tank station panels are charged from the PV system and refill water tanks by signaling the pump station panel when the float switch is activated.}
            % \resumeItem{Implemented motor control circuits by reading their PLC ladder diagrams and analyzed the EPLAN project documentation, HMI, and hardware components of an RTU panel.}
        % \resumeItemListEnd

    % \vspace{15pt}
    \resumeSubheading
      {Meteksan Defense Industry Inc.}{Ankara, Turkey}
      {Analog Design Engineering Intern}{Jul 2021 \textbf{--} Aug 2021}
        \resumeItemListStart
            \resumeItem{Designed numerous analog circuits such as voltage-mode controlled buck converter, phase-shifted full-bridge isolated DC-DC converter, and EMI filters with LTspice. Integrated these circuits and implemented a 320 W power distribution unit to be used in a radar system's power circuit board.}
            \resumeItem{Researched real-world compatible electronic components to be used in such circuits including GaNFETs, high-side gate drivers, and Schottky diodes.}
            \resumeItem{Assembled PCBs of both common and differential mode filters and used VNA Bode 100 to measure the cut-off frequencies.}
        \resumeItemListEnd
    
  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd
```

Comment: The repository you link to appears to be a lightly modified and unmarked copy of https://github.com/sb2nov/resume

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the definitions for `\resumeSubheading` and `\resumeSubSubheading` the intention appears to be for `\resumeSubheading` to be used as `\resumeSubheading{Company}{Location}{Job 1}{Dates 1}`, and then a second role at the same place to be entered after as `\resumeSubSubheading{Job 2}{Dates 2}`, coming under the same company heading.